# How to unload view of UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have custom control like tabbar which displays many controllers some of them also have my tabbar with other controllers, so, my app uses lots of memory because every controller is stored in memory. So I want to unload invisible controller, but I not found any method for unloading UIViewController. How can I do it?

PS. I can not use UITabBarController, really can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. UIViewControllers don't get unloaded in low memory, just their views do.

This happens in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` on your own view controllers and gets called automatically when a low memory warning occurs.

Override this and unload anything that can be re-created in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the view controllers view from it's superview and release the controller. Job done.

Comment: It is not suit, I need to keep controller data - controller load from Internet data and if loading will occurs every time user will expect. Remake to a more MVC version I can not app too big.

Comment: In that case views get automatically unloaded when passed a didReceiveMemoryWarning, but you should now clean up anything in  viewDidUnload which you will recreate in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread but might be usefull for someone.

You can unload viewControllers view by calling:

```
[viewControllerWhoseViewYouWantToUnload didReceiveMemoryWarning];
```